# File -> Open URL... option disappeared?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA used to have a option in the File menu to "Open URL...". However, when I went to use this feature today the option is missing:

[image]

Did a recent update remove this feature or is there a configuration option to restore it?

I'm running:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1 (Ultimate Edition)
>   Build #IU-193.5662.53, built on December 18, 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the File -> Open URL option was provided by the "JavaScript and TypeScript" plugin. Somehow that got disabled which is why the option was missing.

Re-enabling the "JavaScript and TypeScript" plugin fixed the issue.